# Show that $m_2(\mathbb{R})=0$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ as a subset of plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $m_2(E)$ denoted the Lebesgue measure of E in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $m_2(\mathbb{R})=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$m_2(\mathbb{R}\times \{0\}) := \lim_{k\to \infty} m_2([-k,k]\times\{0\})$. So all we need to show is that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ the segment $[-k,k]\times \{0\}$ has zero measure

To do this, we consider the following sequence of sets:
$$ S_n = \left]-k-\frac{1}{n}, k + \frac{1}{n}\right[ \times \left]-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}\right[ $$
It is easy to see that $S_n$ is open and that $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} S_n = [-k,k]\times \{0\}$. Moreover
$m_2(S_n) = \frac{4kn + 4}{n^2}$ so
$$m_2([-k,k]\times \{0\}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} m_2(S_n) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{4kn + 4}{n^2} = 0 $$

So the measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is $0$

Comment: How you can compute $$m_2(S_n)=\frac{4\mathrm{k}}{\mathrm{n}^2}$$

Comment: I edited the answer. It were wrong since the measure of a cell is the product of the lengh of their sides (by definition)